# Eclipse XML formatter

Tags: xml, eclipse, plugins

What is a free alternative to the built-in Eclipse XML editor?

The one packaged with the IDE has two major problems with formatting:

1. The formatter tries to parse escaped char's as though they were unescaped. E.g. '&lt;' is treated like '<' which causes the formatter to "stop".
2. White space between elements is not honored:

   ```
   <foo>   text </foo>
   ```

   will be formatted to:

   ```
   <foo>text</foo>
   ```

We are using Eclipse 3.4.

#### Updates

Issue #1 is a known bug: [Formatting issues with entities in XML files](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=238026).

[Apparently](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=262206#c7) the white space formatting is intended functionality.  I have requested this be provided as an option or advise on fixing this in a plugin of my own, but as of yet, no answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is way less than ideal, and I hope someone has a better solution, but it works:

Build a simple App using dom4j:

```
public static void main( final String[] args ) throws Exception {
    String text = FileUtils.readFileToString( new File( args[ 0 ] ) );
    OutputFormat format = OutputFormat.createPrettyPrint();
    format.setTrimText( false );

    XMLWriter writer = new XMLWriter( System.out, format );
    writer.write( DocumentHelper.parseText( text ) );
}
```

Create a runnable jar, (optional) batch script, and add as an external tool. Of course, you could try XMLTidy or some other command line XML formatter, but I have had better results with dom4j.

Comment: +1. Programming is one of the few professions where you can *create* the tools you then use every day, and more should take advantage of that.

Comment: @Roger: Amen to that. I've wrote quite a few plugins for Eclipse, Maven mojo's, scripts, tools, etc than I think I have "legitimate" projects. It's almost always fun and interesting - and pragmatic to boot :)

Answer (score 2):

I like Notepad++ with the XML Tools plugin.  It does XSLT, has an XPATH expression evaluator, and does DTD and schema validation.  Toolchain download links:

- Notepad++: http://sourceforge.net/project/downloading.php?group_id=95717&use_mirror=internap&filename=npp.5.0.Installer.exe&24657954
- XML Plugins: http://sourceforge.net/project/downloading.php?group_id=189927&use_mirror=voxel&filename=xmltools_2.3.1_r639.zip&44936797
- External Libraries: http://sourceforge.net/project/downloading.php?group_id=189927&use_mirror=internap&filename=ext_libs.zip&52274848

Answer (score 2):

You can try [this one](http://editorxml.sourceforge.net) if you like

Answer (score 1):

I do not see any of those problems when I format (`CTRL+SHIFT+F`) in an [xml editor with **WTP**](http://help.eclipse.org/ganymede/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.wst.xmleditor.doc.user/topics/cwxmledt.html)

So WTP should solve your issues.

[image]
<sub>(source: [springframework.org](http://static.springframework.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/images/eclipse-setup-2.png))</sub>

---

I stand corrected: spaces and escaped characters are indeed an issue with the "XML Editor and Tools" plugin (3.0.2 or 3.0.3) from WTP.

However, `<foo> text </foo>` will not collapsed as `<foo>text</foo>`.

But

```
<foo>    text   text2      text3        </foo>
```

will be formatted as

```
<foo> text text2 text3       </foo>
```

(the spaces at the end are preserved, curiously)

And any escaped character sequence does stop the formatting (every lines until the one including the escaped character are formatted)

I will look deeper in this issue and turn this answer as a community one.

Comment: I have the 'Eclipse XML Editors and Tools 3.0.3' installed already.
Have you tried creating a tag with white space in the data and then formatting? How about escape chars? If it works for you then I wonder if it is some setting...

Answer (score 1):

I have used XMLBuddy in the past
http://www.xmlbuddy.com/

before I reverted to OxygenXML but you have to pay for Oxygen.

Comment: XMLbuddy is not free so far as I can tell.

Comment: p.s. I'd happily pay for\expense a full featured plugin if that is what I needed. However, I just need simple formatting and outline presentation.

Answer (score 1):

The Eclipse XML Editor will honor `CDATA` sections and won't do any formatting within those sections. I tested this with kepler. This is slightly more to type, but one can use a template from `preferences -> XML -> XML Files -> Editor -> Templates` to make this easier.